# How to change dropdown list itens from a form created by model with integration

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

Iḿ trying to change the dropdown list itens in a Form created by Model with Realation on AppMaker.

I tryed to change in Property Editor of the Dropdown list in value and in option but the selection using datasource isnt avaliable to confirm (with Ok).

The field of this relation is the dropdown list where the user will select. The itens list of this dropdown list is the id from the relationed Model, and I want to change to another field like name.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leaving the options binding at

```
@datasources.YourDatasource.items
```

and then setting the names property to

```
@datasources.YourDatasource.items..name
```

In this case the .. will be filled in by your binding 'wizard' when choosing 'Projections', so in your names binding property settings you would choose datasources - YourDatasource - items - projections - then select the field name.